# How to allow command with one discord.py check?

Tags: permissions, discord, discord.py

I have a command in discord.py where I would like to have, for example, `@has_permissions(administrator=True)`, but I want to be able to run the command with, say, a custom check that checks if it is a certain user, so that the user/role/whatever can run the command, regardless of whether or not they have the permission. So I guess my question is this: is there a way to allow a command if a user passes at least 1 check? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer! After reviewing the docs, I found the `@commands.check_any()` decorator. You can input checks for it to check, and if any of the inputted checks will be passed, it adds that check.

Read more about this decorator in the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has%20permissions#discord.ext.commands.check_any).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can write your own check as described in the docs here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has%20permissions#discord.ext.commands.check

```python
def check_if_it_is_me(ctx):
    return ctx.message.author.id == 85309593344815104

@bot.command()
@commands.check(check_if_it_is_me)
async def only_for_me(ctx):
    await ctx.send('I know you!')
```

Comment: My question wasn't how to make a custom check, I know how to do that. My question was, is there a way to run a command even if only one of multiple checks is passed?

Comment: Oh, sorry for misunderstanding your question, glad you found an answer regardless